# Internal EMF of a Synchronous Generator Relationship with Load side line Voltage

Tags: power, generator, load, synchronous

Say you have a 6-pole, star-connected, 60 Hz, 25 MVA rated, 600 V synchronous generator. After conducting open and short circuit tests you get the equivalent circuit with Xs = 600/(root(3)*14000) (where 14000 is the short ciruit current) so Xs = 0.2309j ohms (R_a is ignored). Now that you have your generator reactance you attach the generator to the series of transfomers with certain line impedances. After using the per unit method you get the single line model with a total impedance (could be anything depending on how many transfomers etc you have but let's just say it's 0.5j pu). Now if the final transformer in your power system has a line secondary line voltage of say 33kV but your load is at say for example 30kV with a power of 15 MW and a power factor of 0.6 lagging.

How could the single line model be used to find the internal EMF of the generator such that the load line voltage is kept to 30kV?

My method was: Find the receiving end voltage in pu which is 30/33  = 10/11. Find the load current in pu as the complex power base is let's say 60 MVA. then use KVL around the single line circuit to get the sending in voltage. This (from my understanding) is the terminal voltage of the generator. Then as the armature current is the line current which is the load current in this case, and Xs is known; the internal EMF could then be found from E_A = abs(VT/root(3) - jXsIa).

However, from this I get an E_A which is almost half of the terminal voltage. Which makes no sense as how can you generate more energy than what you have put in?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Something very odd about those numbers ... 25MVA/3 / 600V is about 14000A which doesn't seem compatible with a short circuit current of 1500 (A?) I may be missing something, but not sure you can trust the problem statement enough to attempt a solution.

Comment: Apologies @user_1818839 I was making up numbers as I went and forgot to double check them. But this still results in the same issue of internal EMF being smaller than the terminal voltage.

Comment: I'm with '39, flawed numbers and I'm not going to waste my time...

Comment: SC current = load current would still lead to odd results.